# Need help to understand norms

Tags: functions, normed-spaces

I have some problems to understand norms.

At university, my task was to solve the following question:

$$
Is\;in\;\mathbb{R}^n (n\ge2)\;a\;norm\;defined\;by\;the\;following\;equations?\\
(a)\;\;f_1(x) = |x_1+x_2|\\
(b)\;\;f_2(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n(x_i^2)
$$

At first, i tried to figure out, how a norm is defined.
The charakteristics of a norm I found out are the following:

$$
Norm\;of\;x:= ||x||= \sqrt{x\cdot x}\\
positive\;definite:=||x|| = 0 \rightarrow x = 0\\
homogeneity:=||\lambda x|| = |\lambda|\;||x||\\
triangle\;inequality := ||x+y|| \le ||x||+||y||
$$

If all of them are true, a norm is defined as far as I found out.

The excercise with the sum was easier to solve since the homogeneity was not valid.
Subexcercise a made me some problems since the beginning of my argumentation was wrong. Our exercise instructors unfortunately do not keep on looking on the rest when we make a fault.

I tried to solve the subexcercise (a) as the following:

$$
positive\;definite:=||x|| = 0 \rightarrow x = 0\\
||x_1+x_2|| = 0\;means\; x_1=0=x_2 \rightarrow x=0\;true.
$$

This seemed to be the part where I made a mistake. But why is the statement above wrong? Unfortunately I don't see it.

Comment: Why should $|x_1+x_2|=0$ imply $x_1=0=x_2$? What's $3+(-3)$?

Comment: Well, this makes sense. I have thought that both x have to be the same value. Then this thought was my fault, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition $\|x\|=\sqrt{x\cdot x}$ is for a *particular* norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In your exercise you have two other functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

You have to verify whether the functions so defined have the required properties.

For $f_1(x)$ the positive definedness fails: consider the vector
$$
x=(1,-1,\underbrace{0,\dots,0}_{\text{$n-2$ zeros}})
$$
Then $f_1(x)=0$, but $x\ne0$.

What property fails for $f_2$? Hint: try homogeneity.

---

There's nothing special or magic in the symbol $\|\,{\cdot}\,\|$. It's just a symbol usually employed to denote a function that we already know it's a norm.

If $V$ is a vector space and $f\colon V\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, then $f$ is a norm on $V$ provided:

1. $f(v)\ge 0$, for all $v\in V$;
2. $f(v)=0$ implies $v=0$;
3. $f(\alpha v)=|\alpha|f(v)$ for all $v\in V$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$;
4. $f(v+w)\le f(v)+f(w)$, for all $v,w\in V$.

One can define several norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$; for instance
$$
f(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|,\quad\text{for $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$}
$$
Usually one writes $f(v)=\|v\|_1$. Another one is
$$
g(v)=\sqrt{v\cdot v},\quad\text{where $v\cdot v$ is the usual scalar product}
$$
and this is frequently written as $g(v)=\|v\|_2$ or just $\|v\|$.

Another example:
$$
h(v)=\max\{|v_1|,|v_2|,\dots,|v_n|\},\quad\text{for $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)$}
$$
and this is frequently written $\|v\|_\infty$.

In your exercise, $f_2(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$ doesn't define a norm: if $v=(1,1,\dots,1)$ and $\lambda=2$, you have
$$
f_2(\lambda v)=f_2(2,\dots,2)=4n
$$
while
$$
|\lambda| f_2(v)=2f_2(1,1,\dots,1)=2n
$$
and they're not equal, since $n>0$.

Comment: Is the homogeneity failing because:
$$
f_2(\lambda x) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda x_i)^2 \neq \lambda \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = |\lambda| f_2(x)
$$
?

Comment: @Drudge Yes, but you just need an example: consider the vector $x=(1,\dots,1)$ and $\lambda=2$.

Comment: When I use your example, can I say that
$$
x=(1,...,1)\\
\lambda=2\\
f_2(2*(1,...,1)) \neq 2* f_2(1,...,1)
$$
? If yes, sorry for my misunderstanding, but how do I use
$$
|| \cdot || $$ here, if the definition above is only for a specific norm?

Comment: @Drudge Why should you use $\|\cdot\|$? Use $f_2$, which is the function you're examining.

Comment: I think I have a general misunderstanding what $$ ||\cdot || $$ means. I thought when proving a norm I have to use $$ ||\cdot || $$ somehow but I did not know how:
When examining $$ f_2 $$, do I only have to proove that $$ \lambda x = |\lambda | x $$ without using $$ ||\cdot|| $$ somehow?

Comment: @Drudge That's just a symbol that's frequently used to denote a norm. It means nothing special other than a function.

Comment: That means I can ignore it here when prooving positive definiteness, homogeneity and triangle inequality?

Comment: Oh wait! I got it! The definition of a norm in |R^n for any n is defined by the squareroot of the function f_2. I think, that was even the fact I did not know about. That's why the definition above is only a particular norm. A norm, for n=2. I think, with the equation
$$
||x||\;with\;x =(x_1,...,x_n)\;is\;defined\;as\;\sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^n x_k^2)
$$
I can prove all those three carakteristics.
I just have to check whether
$$
\sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda x_k)^2) = \lambda \sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^n x_k^2)
$$
in excercise (b), right? I think I got it!